# Group by Id but show Name Instead of Id in Report

Tags: reporting, dashboard, custom-report-type, graph

Good day everyone,

I am trying to create a report. I used a summary format of report. Then I group my report by Id of the related list. It is working well. But my problem is that, I want to show the Related list name in the label instead of Id. How will I do it ?

Pls help. Thanks...

Comment: Does your report have access to the Name of the related list? Would you get different results if you grouped by related list name?

Comment: @crmprogdev i'm not sure but I think there would be . Because in my case, There are records that has the same name but different Id.

Comment: I'm confused, do the records you're grouping have the same Id numbers? Are you wanting to "Alias" the Groupings with a Name or do all of the Id's have the same Name? Can you include the Name field in your summary report? If not same Id numbers, by what means are you grouping them? Potential answers would dependent on your response.

Comment: @crmprogdev actually its a related list therefore there are lots of records with the same Id. And in regards with the name there are records that has same name but different Id.

Comment: But I'm guessing all records from the related list won't have the same Id and the same name. I'm guessing you want to use the parent record's Id to group them by? What's the source of the name?

Comment: @crmprogdev Let say for example for example i have a record. The Id is 003123456789123 and the name is "John". And I also have another record which Id is 003123456789987 but the name is "John" also. What I want is to group this record by Id but show name as a label in the report.

Answer (score 1):

I think this isn't possible with the Standard-Report builder. You could fake it, just group first by id and then by name. Not a really nice solution but it worked for me some times.

Or you could use a VF-Page plus reporting API and build everthing by your own, but this way i've never tried.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

From your description, the only way I can think of to do what you're asking is to use "buckets" which is a PITA to do if you have a lot of records. Since you've not presented a screen capture and its still a bit unclear to me how your records are sorted, it sounds as though they look something like the following:

```
ParentId   ParentName    Related Record Id    Related Record Name
Some Id     John          Some Diff Id         John, Joe or even Mary
```

To make your bucketing easier, you might want to create a compound formula field Called `ReportGroup` where it's value `=`Record Id & `Record Name` and use that to do your bucketing with. You'd then more easily be able to tell if you had the both the same `Record Id` and `Record Name` that you wanted to group and assign an Alias of some to the selected records; after which you could hide the formula field from being displayed. Unfortunately, I believe you'd would need to add this field to your database.